# In bash shell on CentOS, what's the proper way to define a function in my ~/.bash_profile file?

Tags: bash, function

I'm using bash shell on CentOS.  I would like to define a function that runs a PostGres 14 query and outputs the result.

```
eth_price 2023-12-06 10:05
```

In my ~/.bash_profile file, I defined

```
eth_price() {
  timestamp="$1:00"  # Append ":00" to the provided timestamp
  PGPASSWORD=$DB_PASS psql -U $DB_USER -d $DB_NAME -c "select price from cryptocurrencyprice p, cryptocurrency c where c.id = p.crypto_currency_id and c.abbrev = 'ETH' and p.created <= '$timestamp' order by created desc limit 1;"
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I get the error

```
-bash: /home/myuser/.bash_profile: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /home/myuser/.bash_profile: line 31: `eth_price() {'
```

What's the proper way to define my function?

**Edit:**

Here is the version output ...

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

And to further isolate the issue, I created my entire ~/.bashrc file to look like the below

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
eth_price() {
  timestamp="$1:00"  # Append ":00" to the provided timestamp
  PGPASSWORD=$DB_PASS psql -U $DB_USER -d $DB_NAME -c "select price from price p, currency c where c.id = p.id and c.abbrev = 'ETH' and p.created <= '$timestamp' order by created desc limit 1;"
}
```

Interestingly, this fails

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
-bash: /home/myuser/.bashrc: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /home/myuser/.bashrc: line 12: `eth_price() {'
```

but this succeeds ...

```
$ sh ~/.bashrc
$
```

Comment: the `source` works for me in a couple different envs (both bash 5.x); what output do you get from `bash --version`?  any chance you may have placed the func def inside another block of code? did you cut-n-paste, or manually type the code, into the file?  if 'cut-n-paste' I'm wondering if you may have introduced some unwanted non-printing characters ... if you copy the file, edit down to just the func def plus a leading/trailing line, and then run `od -c filename`, do you see any characters other than spaces and the characters from the func def?

Comment: I added the version info into my question.  To eliminate the potential issue you raised, I made my entire ~/.bashrc file consist of that function and nothing else.  "source" causes an error, but when I run it against "sh", there is no error.  I included all the output in my edit if it is useful.

Comment: a couple ideas: *1)* put *just* the function definition in a new file by itself and then `source new_file_name`; *2)* modify your current `.bashrc` function defintion to start with `function eth_price()` and then `source .bashrc`; *assuming* one (or both) of these succeed then I'm wondering what's happening with the `. /etc/bashrc` call (ie, what's in `/etc/bashrc`)? any chance there's an alias named `eth_price` in `/etc/bashrc`?

Comment: When I include the word "function" in front then everything works, in as far as there are no more errors (looks like the function doesn't quite do what I want, but fodder for another question).  Prior to that I tried commenting out the lines that included /etc/bashrc and it still failed as before.

Comment: @Dave, what does `alias eth_price` say?

Comment: adding the `function ` prefix would keep `bash` from processing `eth_price()` as an alias invocation with a syntactically invalid trailing `()` (and hence the error message); I was assuming an alias would be defined in your `/etc/bashrc` but what ikkachu's question is referring to ... is there an alias named `eth_price` in your current terminal/shell (where you're running `source ~/.bashrc`)?